# How do I form a SQL query to find all saved searches for a new product?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to allow users to save searches like `{product_type : glasses, price_lt : 100, brand: gucci}` or a search like `{brand : gucci, color: black}`.

When a new product is listed like a black pair of gucci glasses for $99 I want to be able to find any matching saved searches and notify those users. I am storing the users search in a field in the DB called scopes and it is a JSON string because it could have a lot of filters.

Question can I form a SQL query that will find saved searches? Example I would pass the query most of the product info and try to find any records where every condition in the `scopes` field were met. My trouble is say the product has 15 properties and the saved search only has 4 filters, I can't do an `AND` on the 15 properties because the scope only cares about 4 of those.

Secondly if this is a terrible way to do it, then would it be better to have all the filters in separate fields and then just write a query where say `brand = 'gucci' OR brand = NULL` so that if that saved search doesn't care about a brand filter it would still be a potential match?

Sorry just trying to figure out the most performant way. Currently I am just pulling out the searches and looping over them in memory but I know this won't scale when there are thousands of saved searches in the DB and 1000s of products. Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Are your JSON filters sorted? Like aplhabetically or so. And are there only 1 whitespace or can they differ?

Comment: yes. it's possible. if nothing else, you can store the literal sql of the search queries as text, retrieve that text, and re-execute it as queries.

Comment: The JSON is not sorted but could be when we create a new saved search for a user.`scopes = '{"brand":"gucci","price_lt":100,"color":"grey"}'` that is how it currenty looks

Comment: @MarcB My trouble is that i do not want to use the saved search to find all products that match. I want this to be real time run when a new product is added. So it is the opposite direction. I want to find all searches that match a newly added product. Will your suggestion still work? Perfect world I run 1 DB query to get all matching saved searches for the new product

Comment: Sounds like you may want to create a table that contains all these so you can do analytics against it. In that case I would create the tags as columns and you can even look for things like, what are our most popular searches in the last few days? What are people looking for that they can't find?

Comment: Basically if a user want a certain product that is not available or the used ones posted aren't in their price range or what not they could save a search and we could notify them when something new is posted

Comment: storing it as json would be pointless then. mysql doesn't understand anything about json, other than treating it as a text blob. You should re-design your tables so that the search's parameters are stored in a properly normalized design, and then you can run your new items through a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: difficult to get it 100% correct.

Rather than attempt to make the algorithm work for all cases, if real time is important you might get significant benefit from a *filtering* approach that reduces the search space. For example, if your brand is Gucci, you can narrow the searches to those that have "brand: gucci" or don't have "brand". If you apply this to even one or two key fields, you may find you cut the searches you have to check using brute force by 99% - meaning you get the work done in 1% of the time. Experimentation will tell which fields are worth filtering on.

However, your brute force method is the simplest approach, and considering it is only run once per product (ever), performance isn't that important as long as it is not too bad. Your requirement that it run in real time seems unfounded - it can run in batch mode, because IMHO the "requirement" that users be alerted the instant a new product they're interested in becomes available is in reality not needed.

Things you can do to speed it up:

- distribute processing to multiple servers/processes to run search queries in parallel
- run against a copy of the database put in read-only mode and/or with all relevant tables locked in exclusive mode to reduce database locking overheads, and also removing load off your production server
- make each search run faster by adding `AND PRODUCT_ID = x` to the reconstructed search
- batch up all new products and run each search just once checking for all new products in one go (in this case adding `AND PRODUCT_ID IN (x, y, z, ...)` to the query)

If it makes you feel any better, I recently worked at a very large sales web site and they used the brute force method. It worked for them - it can work for you too.

Comment: Thanks. The product like Glasses is an example. In my real world application Real Time is a huge advantage to competition because for what the real application of this is for hours make all the difference. I'll probably end up brute forcing it. Apprecaite the ideas on speeding it up